# I am new on appium and I facing issue to verify number

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I am unable to enter a number in the next column in my script, it's just entering a number in the 1st box and moving onto the next one, when the script goes to write a number in the next one then it's again clearing the 1st text box and rewriting again in the same box instead of next one.

Code:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@index = '0']")).sendKeys("8");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@index = '2']")).sendKeys("7");  
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@index = '3']")).sendKeys("5");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@index = '4']")).sendKeys("9");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@index = '5']")).sendKeys("9");
```

[image: Ui Automator Image]

Comment: It should be `android.widget.EditText` not `TextView` to enter a text

Comment: @MesutGüneş but as you can see in Ui Automator its android.widget.TextView. I have also tried with EditText but its not working.

Comment: appium qui is not working well it possible doesnt show the edittext

Comment: @MesutGüneş I am able to fill first box using TextView but after that every time its writing in same 1st box instead of remaining boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try Sending your complete password to first editBox only. In this case, it should populate remaining text boxes automatically.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@index = '0']")).sendKeys("87599");
```